# Multiply each column of a rowmatrix by an integer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix

I'm wondering what would be a good way of multiply each column of a RowMatrix
 by an integer (each row being multiplied by a different integer).

I know I could for example create a diagonal mllib "Matrix" object containing
the values a1 ... an ( ai being the coefficient I want to multiply the ith 
column of the RowMatrix by ), and then I could just use the matrix multiplication of mllib (multiplying a RowMatrix by a Matrix, which yields a RowMatrix as result). However this is not efficient probably and does not show how to
 do stuff on a RowMatrix.

I'm new to writing functions on rowmatrices and tried looking a bit at some of
the already existing ones and was a bit confused.

Thanks for you help

Comment: It'd help you as well as the answerer if you could add some sample inputs, expected output and your attempts (if any) and produce a [mcve]

Comment: The operation I want to implement is mathematically equivalent to a matrix multiplication on the right by the diagonal matrix diag(a1, ... ,an) if that helps. As mentioned I could just create such a diagonal matrix then use the rowmatrix by matrix multiplication provided in MLLib but this is unefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you want to multiply each row or each column by a different integer. Your title and second paragraph say each column, but your first sentence says each row. Regardless, these sorts of operations are probably most easily implemented by calling `.rows` and operating on the underlying `RDD[Vector]`. For instance:

```
def multiplyColumns(m: RowMatrix, xs: Array[Double]): RowMatrix = {
  val newRowsRdd = m.rows.map {
    row => Vectors.dense(row.toArray.zip(xs).map{case (a, b) => a * b})
  }
  new RowMatrix(newRowsRdd)
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the typo, I meant to say each column, corrected.

Comment: If I'm correct this code does the multiplication column-wise, which is what I meant (equivalent to a matrix multiplication by diag(a1, ... an)), also the code is pretty clear, thank you for your answer.